# Logstash filter - half json line parse

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I'm using 'filebeat' as a shipper an the client send it to redis, read from redis with logstash and send it to ES.

I'm trying to parse the following example line:

> 09:24:01.969 watchdog  - INFO - 100.140.2 PASSED: Mobile:Mobile[].popover["mc1814"].select(2,) :706<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< {"actionDuration":613}

In the end I want to have a field names: "actionDuration" with the value:  613.

As you can see it's partially json.
- I've tried to use grok filter, with add_field and match and I've tried to change a few configurations in the filebeat and logstash.

I'm using the basic configurations:
filebeat.conf:

> filebeat.prospectors:
>
> - input_type: log
>
>   paths:
>
>   - /sketch/workspace/sanity-dev-kennel/out/*.log
>
>   fields:
>
>   - type: watchdog
>   - BUILD_ID: 82161

If there's a possibility to do it in the filebeat side I prefer, but it's also good in the Logstash side.

Thanks a lot,
Moshe

Answer (score 0):

This sort of partial-formatting is best handled on the Logstash side, not the shipper. The filters/transforms available in FileBeat aren't up to that. A Logstash filter pipeline is, though.

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => {
      "message" => [ "(?<plain_prefix>^.*?) (?<json_segment>{.*$)"]
    }
  }
  json {
    source => "json_segment"
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "json_segment" ]
  }
}
```

This basic example will split your incoming message into two fields. a `plain_prefix` and a `json_segment`. The `json{}` filter is then used to parse the JSON data into the event. Finally, a `mutate {}` filter is used to remove the `json_segment` field from the event, as it has already been parsed and included.

**Note:** the `.*?` in the `plain_prefix` is critical in this filter. Constructed this way, everything from the first `{` onward is considered part of the JSON segment. If you use `.*`, the JSON segment will be everything from the *last* `{`, which will be a problem with complex JSON datastructures.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, 
I'm getting the following error:
"json_error": "Error decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type map[string]interface {}",

Comment: It doesn't work to me, I'm using the ELK 5.1.1 stack version, BTW there are some logs without the json in the end.

Comment: @MosheSaada Not without a lot more log-lines to look at, I'm afraid.

Comment: ok it worked but a few fixes:
1.
  grok {
    match => {
      "message" => [ "(?<plain_prefix>^.*?) (?<json_segment>{"actionDuration".*$)"]
    }
  }

2.
  json {
    source => [ "json_segment" ]
  }

Comment: @MosheSaada Ah! Yes, I had a bug in the `source =>` part. It should be a single string, not an array of size one, of strings like you have.

Comment: Another thing, I don't wanna open another thread about similar issue.

I'm adding a prefix to my log line that will say logstash to start parse the line as json, something like {"json_log": ...json....}
13:29:53.934 watchdog - INFO - 100.17.3 PASSED:[3]<<  {"json_log": {"actionDuration":468}}
-
How can I tell logstash to parse as json everything between and drop the prefix: {"json_log": .... } ?

I've created the following regex (that work on grep regex for example) but it doesn't work on logstash:
(?<plain_prefix>^.*?) (?<json_segment>(?<=\"json_log\"\:\ ).*?})
Thx